# How come you need initialisers for all variables when using auto in multiple declarations?

Tags: c++, c++11, declaration, c++14, auto

I would've expected an initialiser would only be necessary for the first declaration. e.g.

```
auto x = 2, y;
```

I would expect this to deduce x's type as int and then implicitly replace "auto" with the base type "int", meaning y would then be a default initialised integer. Actually the entire thing doesn't compile because y explicitly needs and initialiser. Similarly it's odd to me that

```
auto x = 2, y = 3.3;
```

causes an error too. I would've expected y to be initialsed to 3 in a double-to-int conversion, but:

> error: inconsistent deduction for 'auto': 'int' and then 'double'

I read through http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto and couldn't explicitly find an explanation. Actually it seemed like that link was on my side:

> Once the type of the initializer has been determined, the compiler determines the type that will replace the keyword auto using the rules for template argument deduction from a function call (see template argument deduction#Other contexts for details).

Is it simply "just cause"?

Comment: _"Actually it seemed like that link was on my side"_ It's not. Can't see why you think it is.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16642294/560648 http://stackoverflow.com/a/493547/560648

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it simply "just cause"?

Yes.

Both variables have a deduced type, and both variables thus need an initialiser. The logic that requires both to have the same type is applied post-deduction.

> `[C++11: 7.1.6.4/7]:` If the list of declarators contains more than one declarator, the type of each declared variable is determined as described above. If the type deduced for the template parameter `U` is not the same in each deduction, the program is ill-formed.
>
> `[C++14: 7.1.6.4/8]:` If the *init-declarator-list* contains more than one *init-declarator*, they shall all form declarations of variables. The type of each declared variable is determined as described above, and if the type that replaces the placeholder type is not the same in each deduction, the program is ill-formed.

Call it a C++ oddity, but I imagine it's there to help keep the standard wording simple. After all, wouldn't it be a little confusing (and by that I mean more confusing/unclear than `auto` already is) if your example worked as you describe?

Comment: I very much doubt that reasonable behavior was ever compromised for clarity in the standard, which itself is 1350 pages long and brims with complexity in every respect. The real answer to this question would address the actual reasons, not what particular paragraph forbids it.

Comment: @Columbo: Dislike of making wording too complex is hardly unusual. I'm not saying the committee succeeds at it in general.